# How to call internal APEX methods provided by B2B Commerce for Visualforce using REST request

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Our team has a web application developed on top of B2B Commerce for Visualforce, there is a button on Product page, Add to Cart, it will call an Apex remote action method using Javascript when clicking on the button, I checked the network traffic in DevTools, found the following XHR request

[image: details of XHR request]
the above XHR request should be made with the similar code
`CCRZ.CloudCrazeView.addItem(event)`, there is the doc for the class, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_commerce_dev_guide.meta/b2b_commerce_dev_guide/ccrz_CloudCrazeView.htm

does it have a REST API for the method in the picture? if yes any documentation or sources for it, so that I can call the method using HTTP REST requests, I mean calling it with curl, python or java remotely instead of Javascript.

the APEX class is `ccrz.cc_RemoteActionController` and the method is `addItem`, I know B2B Commerce provides a collection of REST API, [REST API Endpoints for B2B Commerce for Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_commerce_dev_guide.meta/b2b_commerce_dev_guide/b2b_commerce_rest_api.htm), but this page doesn't include the method.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2 different annotations and developer might have not used both. For Javascript usage it's `@AuraEnabled` and for being exposed as REST webservice it's `@RestResource` annotation on whole class + possibly `@HttpPost` on the method itself.

The problem is that in given class you can have only 1 of each HTTP "verbs" so if the class supports say 3 different buttons, they all would be accepting data as POST - problem. (in a pinch that dev could have done 1 master method inspecting the service url used, the input params and dispatching to right method for processing but it's bit meh...)

But. You should be able to patch that. Inspect cc_RemoteActionController in setup -> apex classes to confirm the method signature (it should be marked `global` meaning you can call it from apex too).

Create your own class that will act as REST wrapper

```apex
@RestResource(urlMapping='/HiStackoverflow/*')
global with sharing class HiStackoverflow{
    @HttpPost
    global static void addItem(Event e) {
        ccrz.cc_RemoteActionController.addItem(e);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, the tricky thing is that I can't find the apex class `cc_RemoteActionController` in setup -> apex classes, I think it should be apart of B2B Commerce for Visualforce package, I checked the URL of the XHR, which points to the instance of Salesforce ORG running the web application, where can I find the apex class?

Comment: Check if your listviews really show all classes, maybe somebody filtered it to only "your" classes (skip classes from managed packages).  What do you get when you query `select id, name, namespaceprefix
from apexclass
where namespaceprefix = 'ccrz'
order by namespaceprefix, name`? You should be able to find it, grab the ID and just paste it into the url, `mydomain.lightning.force.com/{id goes here}`

Comment: I found the class, it is managed and not defined as global, does it mean I can't create a wrapper class to call the method? if yes do we have any other workaround?

Comment: Try it in developer console's anonymous block, call `ccrz.cc_RemoteActionController.addItem(null)` just to see if it compiles. If it's not exposed as global I expect you to have hard time because of https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_apex_methods_packages_cruc.htm&type=5&release=230. You may have to contact their support and ask for marking the class & method global or some tips how to reimplement the functionality in your custom code

Comment: Is `RemoteInvocation` marked global? I don't fully understand what the hell's going on in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_commerce_dev_guide.meta/b2b_commerce_dev_guide/ccrz_RemoteInvocation_invokeCtx.htm but it looks like some "proxy" to let you call their classes and methods? Something like `new CCRZ.RemoteInvocation('cc_RemoteActionController').invokeCtx('addItem', 'string with item json here maybe?');`

Comment: it showed an error "Type is not visible: ccrz.cc_RemoteActionController" when running the statement.

Comment: `RemoteInvocation` it is Javascript code to run APEX remote action method, but I want to call the method outside of Javascript.